# Vim: Stop Cursor Moving When The Page Scrolls

Tags: vim, scroll, cursor-position

It happens to me many times that I want to look at other parts of the code while writing a statement, but whenever I scroll the page and the cursor reaches the bottom or top of the page it starts scrolling with the page, which means I have to search for the line I have been writing in. This is really annoying. Any idea if this can be disabled or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be disabled, but if you were writing a statement and want to get quickly back to where you were, just hit `gi` and you'll get back to where you were doing your last insert.

Comment: Oh, and you surely need to go to normal mode before searching for what you need, which is quite natural thing to do, I feel.

Comment: OK, gi seems to be great, but I used to scroll using the mouse when I am still in insert mode, so it seems that I have to return back to normal mode before making scroll :-(

Answer (score 2):

Another useful vim trick is setting marks. `m{a-zA-Z}` set a mark {a-zA-Z} at cursor position. You can then send the cursor (and the window) back there by `` `{a-zA-Z} ``.

Comment: Well, that a bit like a task really. So I have to go to normal mode, press ma, then scroll around, then press 'a then go back to insert mode! That is too much :-) But good suggestion anyway, better than having to search the lines to see where I am. What I used to do is type u to undo (this will take me to the last line I was editing), then press ^R to redo the last thing I wrote.

Comment: I don't like using the marks either. Another idea might be `. - Like gi, but it takes to you the last line that has been edited.

Comment: `. (that is the mark named "dot") will take you to the place you did your last edit. Besides, if you are "normally" in insert mode in vim, you may want to rethink your vim using strategy :)

Comment: Read this excellent article about vim modes: http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html to get the idea what I mean

Answer (score 2):

I often split my window when I'm looking at more than one part of a file. `:sp` for a horizontal split, and `:vs` for a vertical split.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is these key strokes:

```
zz , zt and zb
```

The cursor is on the same position, but your windows will move. ( in normal mode of course)

```
zz the cursor position is centered
zt the cursor position is at the top
zb the cursor position is at the bottom
```